# find saturation with a good thershold

Tags: image-processing, matlab

i am new in matlab and i want to have threshold on my image.[I want find the saturation of purple cells in order to distinguish that which one is a cancer one, because the cancer on have specific saturation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRdhQ.jpg)
but i don't know how to do it. here is my code. it never go to the if part!!
in these codes i use red channel, but i guess it is wrong!
in addition the segmentation parts has been done and the purple cells become segmented.
The only thing that i need is a good threshold.
please guide me.. thanks
here is the code:

```
imshow(segmented_images{2})
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(segmented_images{2});
%%segmented_images{2} is a segmented image
Rchannel = hsvImage(:,:,1);
Rchannel=int8(Rchannel);

if Rchannel > 2736*3765

 message = sprintf('it is a cancer image');
    reply = questdlg(message, 'Continue with Demo?', 'OK','cancel', 'OK');
    if strcmpi(reply, 'cancel')
        % User canceled so exit.
        return;
    end
end

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn2X9.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of Rchannel just before the `if` statement?

Comment: it show the red color channel of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question.
  Such threshold's are totally dependent on the data and application you are dealing with. This is what you need to figure out from statistical and emperical analysis of your data. No one here will be able to give you that.

Comment: Ok. so just show me a solution to find saturation of an segmented image or lightness of that.
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be tricky with an automatically calculated binary threshold. Use the color information, if possible. The intensity information alone likely won't be sufficient.

Here are some options to consider:

1. Work in a different color space. RGB is often not as useful a color space as HSI. If you convert to HSI and then plot H vs. S or H vs. I for all pixels in the image, you should be able to spot the differences between the purplish cancer and the colors of the surrounding tissues. It would be much harder to do this in a grayscale image.
2. Instead of binarizing the image, consider using a watershed algorithm. This will segment the image into more that just one foreground and one background. Or, better than that...
3. Try mean shift clustering, which could be very well suited to this problem. Mean shift will find blobs in adjacent, similarly colored regions even if they have weird shapes.

http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~wzhao2/mean_shift.htm

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10161-mean-shift-clustering